# Use the output of a cat command in execution (bash)

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Simple question I think.. but I couldnt find it with google..

I have a file test.txt.. it contains;

```
blah
blah2
blah3
```

What I want to do is;

cat test.txt
and then execute;

```
./script blah
./script blah2
./script blah3
```

But I want to do it in one line.. What would be the best ways to do it.. ? I know using && is a option.. but maybe there are better ways to pass the string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for `cat` (or any other external tool for that matter). Something like:

```
while read line; do ./script "$line"; done < test.txt
```

does what you want, using the shell builtin `read`.

As pointed out in the comments, this assumes that you are in the same directory as the script. If not, replace `./script` with `path/to/script`.

Comment: +1 for beating me in secs....  better change `./script` to a full path. in case the script was in a different dir. but perhaps OP could guarantee that won't happen.

Comment: True, I've added a note to my answer regarding the path.

Answer (score 3):

Using `xargs`:

```
xargs -n 1 ./script < test.txt
```

Comment: This works (so +1) and the `-n` option to `xargs` is good to be reminded about, but the `while read line` technique is probably more generic.